# Ampersand in Python to LaTeX

Tags: python, latex, ampersand

I want to auto-generate a LaTeX document using a string generated by Python. The document contains a table in LaTeX:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Index & Value \\
\hline
{{ }}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

In the place holder {{ }} I enter a string generated by Python:

```
content = "1 & 3.0 \\\ \hline\n 2 & 5.0 \\\ \hline\n"
```

I use the `chevron` package and the `chevron.render` to enter the string content to the TEX file.

The results I get is:
[image: What I get]

That is, I get "amp;" printed in each cell. The "amp;" refers to the character `&` which is used to separated column cell in LaTeX tables.

I want that the table will look like:
[image: What I want]

Playing with it, the problem source is chevron, replacing & with amp;, probably to escape the & in HTML and XML documents.

I tried taking the full file as a string and using Python string.replace("amp;", " & "). This seems to work, but this is not a "textbook solution". Is there a neater way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with chevron, but it *looks* like it is escaping characters which would have special meaning in HTML. This is likely to cause confusion when the output is LaTeX, because its escaping needs are completely different.

Also, it looks like chevron is an implementation of mustache, and [its documentation](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) says

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.

Maybe that is something to try.